# Update multiple fields

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sql-update, mysql-connector

First of all i'm working with the MySQL-Connector / Net and a MySQL Database.
And please don't tell me that i should use using or i don't have try and catch. I have but i just wanted to post a low amount of code.

I want to update multiple fields at one but it is not working. I'm getting an syntax error.

(from comments)I'm getting this error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ 1, allC = allC + 50' at line 1

```
sql_command.CommandText = "Update Test Set x1 + 1 And allC + ?Ammount Where = 1;";
sql_command.Parameters.Add("?Ammount", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = dataTable.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But isn't this right?
I don't really need the where clause because it is just a number table i would say, so there is not more than one row.
But it is also not working if it try it so:

```
sql_command.CommandText = "Update Test Set x1 + 1 And all + ?Ammount;";
```

And there is another question i have.
If i want to get one entry from a database and it's just really one, which is the easiest way to do that?

That's it, but how can i save this record in a string with a low amount of code?

```
sql_command.CommandText = "Select ID From Customer Order By ID Desc Limit 1;";
```

Comment: your query command is hard to read. You should use ` (tick marks) to enclose your columns especially when you have columns named `all` as that is a sql reserved word list https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax for the UPDATE statement is broken beyond repair:

```
Update Test Set x1 + 1 And all + ?Ammount Where = 1;
```

To which field `WHERE = 1` should refer to?
Which field should receive value of the `x1 + 1`?

I don't believe this question can be answered properly unless it is significantly revised; please provide some kind of a description on *what* you want to do with the UPDATE statement.

Also, last SELECT statement can be replaced by the following:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Customer;
```

This would be a bit more readable.

Comment: I'm just trying to update fields in my database. I thought a update statement must use where but i'm not sure. The Table is just for saving ammounts, like how many Customers already have been edited and so on. The Table just has one row and there will be no one added.

Comment: If you are *sure* you only have one row, you don't need to use `WHERE` at all, just leave it out. Can you provide table layout (e.g. `DESCRIBE Test`)

Comment: I've found the error, thanks. But i've also asked another question. How can i save the SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Customer; in a string or something like that with a less ammount of code? and could i also use x1++ or something like that?

Comment: My C#/.Net knowledge is very limited, but based on the documentation you could look into `sql_command.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 2):

Assign your expressions to a column and use a comma (`,`) instead of `And`:

```
Update Test 
  Set x1 = x1 + 1, all = all + ?Ammount 
  Where = 1;
```

Also, your `WHERE` clause is invalid, but I need to more info to fix it for you.

Comment: It stil does not work. I'm getting this error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '+ 1, allC = allC + 50' at line 1

Comment: @user3438236 get rid of the `where = 1;`  if you want to update all rows you dont need a `where` constraint. Though `where 1=1` would work as well.